# Qt library incompatibility with Pycharm new installation

Tags: python, qt, pycharm, conda

I installed a new version of Pycharm (2019.3.1) and running my old codes on them. But I am getting error for qt library incompatibility. I tried to update the qt package from conda (as I am using conda distribution for the python).
I noticed the following behavior -

1. The error comes only for the plotting (which makes sense as qt is for graphical purposes).
2. There is no problem in code compilation and running, as it shows the result for the 1 epoch (can be seen in the below image.
3. My installed qt version is 5.9 (you can see in the second image)

The same code runs perfectly in spider but throwing the below error in pycharm. Please help me to fix this problem. thanks

[image: Error thrown by pycharm]

[image: QT version shown through anaconda console]

Comment: Does all of your code import qt in the same way? Maybe print the output of `conda list qt` and then see if you mixed import qt with import pyqt5 etc. ...

Answer (score 0):

From error message you posted it is clear that you have library incompatibility problem.

Somehow it appears you have 2 Qt versions installed - 5.9.7 and 5.12.4 and these versions have conflict with each other. 
You need to verify Run configuration in PyCharm to see which python environment it uses. And then check why 2 Qt are available in your system.

Anothe option that comes to my mind - your PyQt5 or PySide2 (whatever you use) library is built with Qt 5.12.4 while your system have 5.9.7 and it brings a conflict.